# Debug a New Polymer Element Page

Tags: javascript, html, templates, dom, polymer

We have

`/
 bower_components 
 index_demo.html 
 mycomponent.html`

`mycomponent.html` uses e.g. `paper-button`, which gets imported

`<link rel="import" href="../paper-button/paper-button.html">`

so when mycomponent is installed via bower itself it lands in `bower_components`  and everything works.

Now what is the **best practice** to debug this element locally?

`index_demo.html` should import `mycomponent.html` and some `bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html`.

Now `mycomponent.html` doesn't work, because

`../paper-button/paper-button.html` is not found (as it lies in `bower_components/paper-button`)

For now I manually add required mycomponent polymer elements into the `index_demo.html`, but it's a somewhat unclean solution.

Platform: Win

Comment: Are you using the `seed-element` structure described in this [guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/reusableelements.html)? If  you aren't I'd recommend you to use it, it has pretty much everything you need to develop, debug, test, deploy you element to github pages, and put into bower

Comment: Thank you, let me look into that

Comment: @Alan post that comment as an answer for cookies ( ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems my comment was helpful, here it is as an answer

There's a [guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/reusableelements.html) in the Polymer website on the recommended way of creating new elements with Polymer, in it you can find the download link for the `seed-element` template which has an structure that allows you to develop, debug, test, deploy you element to github pages, and put it into bower quite easily.

Comment: The most helpful part was the very last paragraph :D! "The easiest way to fix this is by setting up a local server that remaps the paths so that all of the components in bower_components appear to be in sibling directories to my-element. Polyserve does this for you automatically."